# Soomla + Cardboard = Linker error in xCode

Tags: ios, linker, mach-o, google-cardboard, soomla

I am developing an app using Google Cardboard SDK as well as Soomla for social network functionality.

Since adding soomla and the FB sdk to the project I have encountered a nasty linker error:

symbols for architecture arm64:   "gvr::CreateMainApp__EXPECTED_EXACTLY_ONE_VR_MAIN_APP_STATEMENT_

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this issue? does Soomla need to be the main app activity?

I have been stuck on this for days now.....

Comment: have you tried http://answers.soom.la/ ?

Comment: See here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674100/linker-error-createmainapp-expected-exactly-one-vr-main-app-statement-with